# Nginx - Conditionally serve WebP when nginx is setup as reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, cache

Trying to conditionally serve WebP images in browsers that accept that mime type. Not being very familiar with nginx, I'm having issues implementing a known solution into my existing default host configuration.

Mainly I'm concerned with using this snippet:

```
try_files $uri$webp_suffix $uri =404;
```

In full, I'm attempting to use the below method of implementing WebP:

```
  map $http_accept $webp_suffix {
    "~*webp"  ".webp";
  }
  map $msie $cache_control {
      "1"     "private";
  }
  map $msie $vary_header {
      default "Accept";
      "1"     "";
  }

  # if proxying to another backend and using nginx as cache
  proxy_cache_path  /tmp/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=my-cache:8m max_size=1000m inactive=600m;
  proxy_temp_path /tmp/cache/tmp;

  server {
    listen       8081;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
      # set response headers specially treating MSIE
      add_header Vary $vary_header;
      add_header Cache-Control $cache_control;
      # now serve our images
      try_files $uri$webp_suffix $uri =404;
    }

    # if proxying to another backend and using nginx as cache
    if ($http_accept ~* "webp")    { set $webp_accept "true"; }
    proxy_cache_key $scheme$proxy_host$request_uri$webp_local$webp_accept;

    location /proxy {
      # Pass WebP support header to backend
      proxy_set_header  WebP  $webp_accept;
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
      proxy_cache my-cache;
    }
  }
```

[from here](https://github.com/igrigorik/webp-detect/blob/master/nginx.conf)

But trying to find a way to merge it with my existing proxy config has been getting me nothing but errors. My existing config (AWS Elastic BeanStalk on Node.js) appears to be reverse proxied to a node process.

My existing nginx_proxy file:

```
upstream nodejs {
    server 127.0.0.1:8081;
    keepalive 256;
}

server {
    listen 8080;


    if ($time_iso8601 ~ "^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2})") {
        set $year $1;
        set $month $2;
        set $day $3;
        set $hour $4;
    }
    access_log /var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.$year-$month-$day-$hour healthd;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;


    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://nodejs;
        proxy_set_header   Connection "";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

gzip on;
gzip_comp_level 4;
gzip_types text/html text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;


}
```

How do I impliment this without messing up my preexisting configurations?

Answer (score 0):

Added several lines could be.

```
map $http_accept $webp_suffix { "~*webp"  ".webp"; }
types { 
    # ensure the nginx supports the mime type
    image/webp webp;
}
location ~* \.(?:ico|cur|gif|svg|svgz|png|jpe?g)(\?.+)?$ {
    try_files $uri$webp_suffix $uri =404;
}
```

The following is the complete nginx conf:

```
upstream nodejs {
    server 127.0.0.1:8081;
    keepalive 256;
}
map $http_accept $webp_suffix { "~*webp"  ".webp"; }
types { 
    image/webp webp;
}
server {
    listen 8080;

    if ($time_iso8601 ~ "^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2})") {
        set $year $1;
        set $month $2;
        set $day $3;
        set $hour $4;
    }
    access_log /var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.$year-$month-$day-$hour healthd;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://nodejs;
        proxy_set_header   Connection "";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
    location ~* \.(?:ico|cur|gif|svg|svgz|png|jpe?g)(\?.+)?$ {
        try_files $uri$webp_suffix $uri =404;
    }
gzip on;
gzip_comp_level 4;
gzip_types text/html text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

}
```

Comment: I think it may be AWS overwriting my configurations. But this doesn't appear to do anything for me. Images still return as normal without replacement. In the mean time decided to implement webp support via `<picture>` element instead.